# Exchange a single dependency

Tags: swift-package-manager

I use a stack build on Swift PM. However, the maintenance of the stack is currently a bit dormant, and my pull requests are no longer incorporated.

I already forked most of the stack anyway to provide pull requests. But I was hesitant to move to a wholly re-created stack as I think it would only make the tech stack even less valuable.

Now, I need to exchange one package with my version. Multiple dependency paths (dependency network) exist on the same package, so I would need to replace the dependency for all the other paths (which would lead to a second stack altogether). This is a quick drawing of the situation: [image]

1. Is there a way to tell Swift PM to override the repository and use my version for the whole dependency network?
2. How do others manage similar situations?